# How to deal with Ruby 2.1.2 memory leaks?

Tags: ruby, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a worker process which spawns up to 50 threads and do some async operations (most of which are http calls). When I start up the process, it starts with some 35MB of used memory, and quickly grows to 250MB. From that point it grows further more and the problem is that the memory never stops growing (even though the growing phase decreases over time). After several days, process just outgrows the available memory and crashes.

I did a lot of analysis and profiling and can't seem to find what is wrong. Process memory is constantly growing, even though the heap size is pretty much constant. I've collected `GC.stat` output into spreadsheet that you can access here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17TohDNXQ_MXM31CeAmR2ptHFYfvOeF3dB6WCBkBS_Bc/edit?usp=sharing

Even though it seems that the process memory has finally stabilized at 415MB, it will continue to grow over next couple of days until it reaches 512MB limit and crashes.

I've also tried tracking objects with objectspace, but the sum of memory of tracked objects never crosses 70-80MB which perfectly aligns with GC reports. Where are the remaining 300MB+ (and growing) spent.. i have no clue.

How to deal with these kinds of problems? Are there any tools that could give me clearer insight on how the memory is being consumed?

UPDATE: Gems and OS

I'm using following gems:

```
gem "require_all", "~> 1.3"
gem "thread", "~> 0.1"
gem "equalizer", "~> 0.0.9"
gem "digest-murmurhash", "~> 0.3", require: "digest/murmurhash"
gem "google-api-client", "~> 0.7", require: "google/api_client"
gem "aws-sdk", "~> 1.44"
```

The application is deployed on heroku, though memory leak is noticable when running it locally on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

UPDATE: Leaks

I've upgraded stringbuffer and analyzed everything like @mtm suggested and now there are no memory leaks identified by `leak` tool, no increases in ruby heap size over time, and yet, the process memory is still growing. Originally I thought that it stopped growing at some point, but several hours later it outgrew the limit and process crashed.

Comment: What native gems are you using? And what OS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From your GC logs it appears the issue is not a ruby object reference leak as the `heap_live_slot` value is not increasing significantly. That would suggest the problem is one of:

1. Data being stored outside the heap (Strings, Arrays etc)
2. A leak in a gem that uses native code
3. A leak in the Ruby interpreter itself (least likely)

It's interesting to note that the problem exhibits on both OSX and Heroku (Ubuntu Linux).

#### Object data and the "heap"

[Ruby 2.1 garbage collection](http://tmm1.net/ruby21-rgengc/) uses the reported "heap" only for Objects that contain a tiny amount of data. When the data contained in an Object goes over a certain limit, the data is moved and allocated to an area outside of the heap. You can get the overall size of each data type with [ObjectSpace](http://tmm1.net/ruby21-objspace/):

```
require 'objspace'
ObjectSpace.count_objects_size({})
```

Collecting this along with your GC stats might indicate where memory is being allocated outside the heap. If you find a particular type, say `:T_ARRAY` increasing a lot more than the others you might need to look for an array you are forever appending to.

You can use [`pry-byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) to drop into a console to troll around specific objects, or even looking at all objects from the root:

```
ObjectSpace.memsize_of(some_object)
ObjectSpace.reachable_objects_from_root
```

There's a bit more detail on one of the [ruby developers blog](http://tmm1.net/ruby21-objspace/) and also in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956401/how-do-i-track-down-a-memory-leak-in-my-ruby-code). I like their JRuby/[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html) profiling idea.

#### Testing native gems

Use [`bundle`](http://bundler.io/) to install your gems into a local path:

```
bundle install --path=.gems/
```

Then you can find those that include native code:

```
find .gems/ -name "*.c"
```

Which gives you: (in my order of suspiciousness)

- digest-stringbuffer-0.0.2
- digest-murmurhash-0.3.0
- nokogiri-1.6.3.1
- json-1.8.1

OSX has a useful dev tool called [`leaks`](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/leaks.1.html) that can tell you if it finds unreferenced memory in a running process. Not very useful for identifying where the memory comes from in Ruby but will help to identify when it is occurring.

First to be tested is [`digest-stringbuffer`](https://github.com/ksss/digest-stringbuffer). Grab the example from the Readme and add in some GC logging with [gc_tracer](https://github.com/ko1/gc_tracer)

```
require "digest/stringbuffer"
require "gc_tracer"
GC::Tracer.start_logging "gclog.txt"
module Digest
  class Prime31 < StringBuffer
    def initialize
      @prime = 31
    end

    def finish
      result = 0
      buffer.unpack("C*").each do |c|
        result += (c * @prime)
      end
      [result & 0xffffffff].pack("N")
    end
  end
end
```

And make it run lots

```
while true do
  a=[]
  500.times do |i|
    a.push Digest::Prime31.hexdigest( "abc" * (1000 + i) )
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

Run the example:

```
bundle exec ruby ./stringbuffertest.rb &
pid=$!
```

Monitor the resident and virtual memory sizes of the `ruby` process, and the count of `leaks` identified:

```
while true; do
  ps=$(ps -o rss,vsz -p $pid | tail +2)
  leaks=$(leaks $pid | grep -c Leak)
  echo "$(date) m[$ps] l[$leaks]"
  sleep 15
done
```

And it looks like we've found something already:

```
Tue 26 Aug 2014 18:22:36 BST m[104776  2538288] l[8229]
Tue 26 Aug 2014 18:22:51 BST m[110524  2547504] l[13657]
Tue 26 Aug 2014 18:23:07 BST m[113716  2547504] l[19656]
Tue 26 Aug 2014 18:23:22 BST m[113924  2547504] l[25454]
Tue 26 Aug 2014 18:23:38 BST m[113988  2547504] l[30722]
```

Resident memory is increasing and the leaks tool is finding more and more unreferenced memory. Confirm the GC heap size, and object count looks stable still

```
tail -f gclog.txt | awk '{ print $1, $3, $4, $7, $13 }
1581853040832 468 183 39171 3247996
1581859846164 468 183 33190 3247996
1584677954974 469 183 39088 3254580
1584678531598 469 183 39088 3254580
1584687986226 469 183 33824 3254580
1587512759786 470 183 39643 3261058
1587513449256 470 183 39643 3261058
1587521726010 470 183 34470 3261058
```

Then report the [issue](https://github.com/ksss/digest-stringbuffer/issues/1).

It appears to my very untrained C eye that they allocate both a [pointer](https://github.com/ksss/digest-stringbuffer/blob/e79e33c6ecf248b3365ad5a5672fe02f7ec31c27/ext/digest/stringbuffer/init.c#L52) and a [buffer](https://github.com/ksss/digest-stringbuffer/blob/e79e33c6ecf248b3365ad5a5672fe02f7ec31c27/ext/digest/stringbuffer/init.c#L20) but only clean up the [buffer](https://github.com/ksss/digest-stringbuffer/blob/e79e33c6ecf248b3365ad5a5672fe02f7ec31c27/ext/digest/stringbuffer/init.c#L40).

Looking at `digest-murmurhash`, it seems to only provide functions that rely on StringBuffer so the leak might be fine once stringbuffer is fixed.

When they have patched it, test again and move onto the next gem. It's probably best to use snippets of code from your implementation for each gem test rather than a generic example.

#### Testing MRI

First step would be to prove the issue on multiple machines under the same MRI to rule out anything local, which you've already done.

Then try the same Ruby version on a different OS, which you've done too.

Try the code on JRuby or Rubinius if possible. Does the same issue occur?

Try the same code on 2.0 or 1.9 if possible, see if the same problem exists.

Try the head development version from github and see if that makes any difference.

If nothing becomes apparent, [submit a bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/) to Ruby detailing the issue and all the things you have eliminated. Wait for a dev to help out and provide whatever they need. They will most likely want to reproduce the issue so if you can get the most concise/minimal example of the issue set up. Doing that will often help you identify what the issue is anyway.

Comment: Whoa! Thank you man! I've learned SO MUCH from your answer. Now I can tackle similar situations on my own. Thank you for solving the issue that's been haunting me for weeks!

Comment: No worries. The same basic technique holds for most interperated/vm languages. First look at your own object leaks. Then module object leaks. Then native code modules. Then the underlying VM.  I've supported a lot of bad Java/JNI apps!

Comment: Initially, I thought this solved the problem since the memory was growing at slower phase and it stopped growing at some 200MB. However, over several hours, memory kept growing in bursts (e.g. it was steady for 10 mins, then suddenly grew for few megabytes) until it reached 512MB and crashed. Can you recommend any next steps now?

Comment: Do the standalone tests of the other native gems (using code from your worker) exhibit the leaky behaviour?

Comment: Nope. I've tested other gems, and I have also tested my entire application for leaking. There is none that `leak` command can detect.. yet process memory grows (slower than before) but still does grow

Comment: I guess you need to look back up higher at the Ruby objects or down further at MRI as well then. I read a bit more about the Ruby garbage collector and it looks like it's only an object heap so some data may not appear in those stats, I've added some detail and links to the dev info.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Unfortunately, I can't try it with ruby 2.0 since I rely on some 2.1 features heavily. However, I did tried it with ruby 2.2-dev and locally it does seem to solve the memory issue! Too bad I can't test it on heroku though. Thank you once again. Your help is much appreciated. I'll just have to wait until new release of ruby is published then.

Comment: Thank you so much once again for this answer. I've faced ruby 2.2 memory leaking lately, and your comment was very useful. It resulted in discovering that ruby StringIO.write was leaking memory (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/785#issuecomment-95456838)

Comment: Cool. Glad it's been of use

Answer (score 1):

I fix memory leak and release digest/stringbuffer v0.0.3.

https://rubygems.org/gems/digest-stringbuffer

You can try again by v0.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm author of digest/murmurhash and digest/stringbuffer gems.

Indeed, It seems like have leaks in digest/stringbuffer.

I'll fix it later.

Can you explain more code?

I recommend using singleton methods like this.

```
Digest::MurmurHash1.hexdigest(some_data)
```

Maybe, It's not leak since singleton methods are not using digest/stringbuffer.

Comment: In fact I was only using singleton method `Digest::MurmurHashAligned2.hexdigest(string)`. I thought that the issue was fixed when upgrading to latest version of your gem.. but it is still present. Damn

Comment: It probably doesn't have anything to do with your gems though